# Default controller key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a laravel route like below :

```
 Route::group(['namespace' => 'Aggregate\Customer\Controller\v1_0','middleware' => 'jwt.auth', 'prefix' => 'api/v1.0/{lang}'], function () {
    Route::put('customer/{id}', 'CustomerController@update_customer');
 });
```

And i want to `lang` key on route `'prefix' => 'api/v1.0/{lang}'` be first variable globally in all methods and in all controllers without manual added in all methods like :

See **$lang**

```
public function add_address_book($lang,$user_id,AddressBookRequest $request)
{
```

How can i do that?

Comment: please help me friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is update the config var `app.locale`.

```
Route::group([
  'namespace' => 'Aggregate\Customer\Controller\v1_0',
  'middleware' => 'jwt.auth',
  'prefix' => 'api/v1.0/{lang}'
], function () {
  App::setLocale(app('request')->segment(3));

  Route::put('customer/{id}', 'CustomerController@update_customer');
});
```

Then use

```
echo App::getLocale();
```

You can set the default locale and the fallback locale in app/config.php

Another option is to set up a singleton in the app container

```
Route::group([
  'namespace' => 'Aggregate\Customer\Controller\v1_0',
  'middleware' => 'jwt.auth',
  'prefix' => 'api/v1.0/{lang}'
], function () {
  app()->singleton('lang', function () {
    return app('request')->segment(3);
  });

  Route::put('customer/{id}', 'CustomerController@update_customer');
});
```

Then in your controllers (or anywhere) you can use

```
echo app('lang');
```